# Using SQL Server 2014 in memory table with arabic collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, oltp

I'm going to use SQL Server 2014 in memory table with a database which has `Arabic_CI_AS` collation but when I create in memory table is says oltp does not support this collation.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Example code? I've created a test database in SQL Server 2014 with Arabic_CI_AS collation and can create in memory tables without problems. Does the information in the following link illuminate things? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn133182.aspx